# Slicing, list assignment and deep/shallow copy

Tags: python, list, slice

From the problem 'Removes any element from L1 that also occurs in L2'

1. first case

```
def removeDups(L1, L2):
    L3 = L1[:] 
    for e1 in L3:
        print('L3' + str(L3))
        print('L1: ' + str(L1))
        if e1 in L2:
            L1.remove(e1)
L1 = [1,2,3,4]
L2 = [1,2,5,6]
removeDups(L1, L2)
```

Output:

```
L3[1, 2, 3, 4]
L1: [1, 2, 3, 4]
L3[1, 2, 3, 4]
L1: [2, 3, 4]
L3[1, 2, 3, 4]
L1: [3, 4]
L3[1, 2, 3, 4]
L1: [3, 4]
```

2. second case

```
def removeDups(L1, L2):
    for e1 in L1[:]:
        print('L1[:]: ' + str(L1[:]))
        print('L1: ' + str(L1))
        if e1 in L2:
            L1.remove(e1)
L1 = [1,2,3,4]
L2 = [1,2,5,6]
removeDups(L1, L2)
```

Output:

```
L1[:]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
L1: [1, 2, 3, 4]
L1[:]: [2, 3, 4]
L1: [2, 3, 4]
L1[:]: [3, 4]
L1: [3, 4]
L1[:]: [3, 4]
L1: [3, 4]
```

Two things confuse me:

1. why would the second case even work? I suspect, slicing makes a shallow copy of L1, and the hidden counter in for loop would ignore the element `2` as L1[:]'s first element is removed too. Thus `2` is in index 0 after the first element is removed. In general, why is this element still accessed by the for loop? That's why I suspect it should print as below:

```
L1[:]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
L1: [1, 2, 3, 4]
L1[:]: [2, 3, 4]
L1: [2, 3, 4]
L1[:]: [2, 3, 4]
L1: [2, 3, 4]
```

2. Why would L3 in the first case remain in the original list after L1 removed some elements?
   What is the mechanism for this line of code`L3 = L1[:]`. Is it something like a deep copy? I thought it just gets a shallow copy of L1 eventually.

Comment: Yes, slicing makes a shallow copy. So case 1 and case 2 are looping the same way, the only difference is that case 1 gave the name `L3` to the copy, while case 2 uses it anonymously.

Comment: Slicing makes a *shallow copy* of a list, not a deep copy - but none of your lists have nested lists (or other containers), so there is no difference between a shallow and a deep copy.

Comment: Your second question seems to imply that you don't understand what a shallow copy is. When you make a shallow copy, modifications to one copy don't affect the other copy. If you had nested containers, modifications to these containers would be seen in both copies (that's the difference between shallow and deep copying).

Comment: "I suspect, slicing makes a shallow copy of L1, and the hidden counter in for loop would ignore the element 2 as L1[:]'s first element is removed too. " No. **Because** a shallow copy was made, the for loop does not ignore the element that was removed from the original list, **because** you are iterating over a copy. That's the whole purpose of a *copy*.

Comment: "Why would L3 in the first case remain in the original list after L1 removed some elements?" Because `L3` and `L1` refer to *two different lists*. `L3` receives a (shallow) copy of `L1`. So *modifications to one list do not affect modifications to the other list*. That is what a copy does. Shallow *or* deep

Comment: @Barmar. Thank you. Say I get a list containing other lists as part of objects. If I created a shallow copy of the original list and modify the nested list, both sides would see the differences? And only the modified one sees the difference in the case if I made a hard copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these lines are equivalent and create a shallow copy.

```py
L3 = L1[:]
L3 = list(L1)
L3 = L1.copy()
L3 = [x for x in L1]
```

shallow copying L1 to L3 is equivalent to passing L1[:] to the loop,

something that confuses new people is the difference between a shallow copy, a deep copy, and an assignment.

```py
L3 = L1  # assignment, modifications to L1 affects L3 and vice versa
L3 = L1[:]  # shallow copy, allocated a new block of memory that gets assigned to L3
L3 = copy.deepcopy(L1)  # deep copy, makes a deep copy of each element of L1 as well as L1 itself.
```

for immutable types such as numbers or strings you won't find difference between the last 2, but if L1 was a list of lists, then those lists will be shared in the case of a shallow copy, but won't be shared in the case of a deep copy, and any modification to L1 elements won't affect L3 elements.

i am also obligated to post this link to [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 1):

The first case and the second case aren't the same.

In the first case, as you suspect, you create a *shallow* copy of `L1`.
And in the second case you check the mutated value of `L`. The slicing doesn't change this matter.

```py
def removeDups(L1, L2):
    for e1 in L1[:]:  # Create a shallow copy of L1
        print('L1[:]: ' + str(L1[:]))  # Check current state of L1 new slice
        print('L1: ' + str(L1))  # Check current state of L1
        if e1 in L2:
            L1.remove(e1)
```

So even though you check a copy of `L1` it changes with each loop, as you always check the mutated version of `L1`. `L3` on the other hand doesn't change, as it is a new object. So the call to `L3` will always give the original list.

The for loop still works, as the `L1[:]` in `for e1 in L1[:]` is only evaluated at the beginning of the loop. So you iterate over a shallow copy of `L1`.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing create a new list, and as you said is a shallow copy of the original list by only keeping the references of the objects it contains.

Now, for your first question:

Why wouldn't it ? Sementically, it is exactly the same, with only L3 being created anynonymously. In the iterator L1[:] is only executed once, create the sliced list, and then your code iterate over it. Reference to L1 can't affect this anonymously created list, because it has not the same reference !

For your second question: it almost the same as your previous question, and you're prints allows to understand:

```
L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L3 = L1[:]
```

So L3 is now:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but if we do :

```
>>> L3 is L1
False
```

The list is ... a copy !